# @import not importing and no errors

Tags: css, wufoo

I am using [Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/) and adding in a custom CSS style sheet (form-change.css) and since I can't change the HTML I am trying to import font from Google using @import but it is doing nothing. No errors in console and no syntax errors. The form is at https://ambrite.wufoo.eu/forms/send-us-a-message/

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow);

#errorLi
{
    display: none;
}

form span.req 
{
  display: none !important;
}

form li.error 
{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
/*
 - Not working either

@font-face
{
    font-family: pt-sans-narrow;
    src: url(
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B-rTml2dkuMnNHBzaDRSckhzRjQ);
}
*/
.wufoo
{
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Paste your code here for us to see.  Don't put us to other websites.

Comment: have you tried putting the url in quotes?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Double or single quotes.